# how to transfer row to jsonb and set name of keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table person with fields: id, first_name, last_name.
Query:

```
select COALESCE( array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(data))), '{}'::json)
from (select id, first_name as firstName from person) data)
```

return this result:

```
  {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": Alex
  }
```

how to get a result:

```
  {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": Alex
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquoted identifiers are folded to lower case in Postgres, so you need to use quoted identifier:

```
select COALESCE(jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(data)), '{}'::jsonb)
from (
   select id, first_name as "firstName" 
   from person
) data
```